# How come one of my Rails views can access my d3.json file but the other view can't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

My json file is located in the "public" folder. My code accesses it this way:

```
d3.json("us-states.json", function(json) {
```

I have two views that need to access the json. One of the views, sessions/new.html.erb, can access it, but the other view can't.

The one that can't is a nested model, user.maps. In the console, I get this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/users/1/maps/us-states.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Why doesn't it look in the "public" folder like the other view does?

Now here's something weird: I experimented a little, and tried changing the path to this:

```
  d3.json("../../../us-states.json", function(json) {
```

When I try that, at first I get this in the console:

```
d3.tip.v0.6.3.js:225 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
```

which appears to be related to d3.tooltip. If I remove my tooltip code, I just get a blank page, no console errors.

But when I reload that page, it finds my JSON and works!

That's not useful, because I can't just reload the page to make it work under normal conditions.

To summarize: if I try "us-states.json", it never works. If I try "../../../us-states.json", it works only on page reload.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`us-states.json` is a relative path, which means it's relative to the current page URL. You can use an absolute path instead to make sure that the same URL is used on all your pages. I suppose it needs to be `/us-states.json` in your case.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that, it still only works if I reload the page, not when the page first loads.

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache? Also, do you use `turbolinks` (in this case you might need to adjust the javascript)?

Comment: I do use turbolinks. I don't know if I need to though. Would getting rid of it help?

Comment: Getting rid of turbolinks didn't help.

Comment: I got it working. See my answer. Thanks for the help @lest!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working. My function was inside a `$(document).ready()` block. I took the function outside of that block, and instead of calling it there, I called it inside some `<script>` tags in my html.erb views, and now it works properly.

I also had to put a slash in front of the path, as @lest suggested.